# How to add OnclickListener() for a Button within a Inflated View?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Im new To StackOverFlow and my prob is im just creating an app which has tabs in it and i want to add the same layout content say layout.xml to all the tabs and the layout.xml has a button within it and it has some textboxes.  Whenever the button is pressed i want to calculate a value using the textbox content.  Im inflating the layout.xml for each new tab but onClickListener() is not working for tabs... Can any one Help Me ...
Please....

```
    TabSpec spec = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final View sem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.semester, null);

                Button Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
                Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View paramView) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        counter++;
                        LinearLayout A = createNewSubject();
                        ((ViewGroup) sem).addView(A);
                    }
                });
                return sem;
```

This is my Code to Add a New Tab....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem is with given below line

```
 Button Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
```

you have to use this

```
 Button Add = (Button)sem.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
```

Comment: Thank You... Can u please tell me some suggestions in sharing data between tabs???? Thank You in Advance....

Comment: What kind of data you want to share ?

Comment: I want Share a integer value from each tab and at the end want derive the result from those integers....

Comment: I am a new android developer and now im working with a proj in which i use viewpager and tabbed view for providin tabs with swipe views. And in each tab i hav a button when ta button is clicked a new text view will be added to the view and it works But my Prob is when i go to some other tab and revisit this tab all textview gets disappeared!! Its not actually Saving the Changed View of the Tab..... I'm Strugglin with this prob for last one week!!! Please Help Me!!!.... Thank u in advance.....